# Олимпиадная задача // Путь белки

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, геометрия

у меня возникли некоторые проблемы с одной задачей.Вот краткое условие:

> Есть дерево, по которому бежит белка по спирали. За один виток она поднимается на h, высота дерева равна H, длина окружности дерева равна S. Какое расстояние преодолеет белка?Вводные данные должны быть числами целого типа
>
> Пример: h=4, H=16, S=3;
>   Результат: 20.0000

Я пытался развязать разными способами:

1. Искал диаметр дерева(d=2*(S/(2*M_PI)));.Потом за формулой
   l=sqrt(h*h+(M_PI*d)^2) искал длину одного витка. Нашел количество
   витков(H/h). Потом умножал количество на l;
2. Считал дерево как цилиндр, на котором есть винтовая линия. Как бы
   развертывал этот цилиндр, и по сути у меня получался прямоугольник со
   сторонами H и S, а также диагональ.Снова нашел количество витков,
   умножил на S и искал по формуле диагональ d=sqrt((H*H)+(Sk*Sk));

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <math.h>

   int main() {
     int h, H, S;
     scanf("%i %i %i", &h, &H, &S);
     float d,k,l;
     k=H/h;
     d=sqrt((h*h)+(S*S));
     l=d*k;
     printf("%.4f", l);
   }
   ```

Comment: чем вторая формула не устраивает?

Comment: @Эникейщик, тем, что диагональ там вообще не при чём? UPDATE: Хотя да, диагональ есть. UPDATE: Тьфу, запутался.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Прямоугольник `S*H`
- Вектор скорости `(S,h)`
- Длина пути `H/h * len(S,h)` = `H/h * sqrt(S*S+h*h)`
- Подставляем данные из условия и получаем `20` ровно

PS: Деление надо выполнять в дробных числах, не целых.

Comment: Та же самая формула, что в вопросе...

Comment: @Эникейщик 1. Не вижу в вопросе такой формулы. 2. У меня ответ сходится с желаемым. 3. Что не так-то?

Comment: Суть в том, что пример то правильно выходит, но другие ответы не сходятся.

Comment: @NazPolinyk, я добавил PS - посмотри.

Comment: В последней строчке она. Путь за один круг. Теорема Пифагора.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, действительно, формула вроде подходящая, все типы данных вроде бы соблюдены, но все же сайт на котором мы проверяем решения выдает неправильный ответ, возможно есть что-то, что мы не учитываем.

Comment: @NazPolinyk, формат вывода, например. Сколько знаков после точки надо выводить и сколько выводишь ты?

Answer (score 4):

За один оборот (виток) вокруг дерева белка по горизонтали (по горизонтальной окружности) проходит `3`, а по вертикали `4`. Расстояние по теореме Пифагора `5`. Поднимется до верха за `16 / 4 = 4` витка. Пройдет `4 * 5 = 20`.

---

Вы, главное, ни в коем случае не показывайте нам Ваш код. Мы будем гадать, что в нем не так. Это такая игра.

---

Справа от знака `=` - целочисленное вычисление:

```
k=H/h;
```

Надо:

```
k = (1.0 * H) / h;
```

Отметьте ответ Qwertiy как правильный. Он угадал раньше.

Comment: Здравствуйте, я делал так раньше, к сожалению это не верный ответ, так как этот ответ проходит тест, другие же - нет.

Comment: @NazPolinyk Это верный ответ. А вот код у вас неверный.

Comment: @NazPolinyk "этот ответ проходит тест, другие же - нет" - Что это, черт возьми, значит? Какие другие ответы? В чем они выражаются?

Comment: В условии должны быть целые числа, щас исправлю.